# How to query dat from two tables and sort them by their date? (Activerecord)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two table to query which is Comments and Summons.

**Comments table:**

[image]

**Summons table:**

[image]

These two tables are belong to the Post table. And I want to query data from each table that belong to the Post, then sorting them according to their date. Below here is the result that I am trying to achieve:

[image]

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest (but not the most efficient) solution.

```
post_id = 1
entries = []
entries.concat Comment.where(post_id: post_id)
entries.concat Summon.where(post_id: post_id)
entries.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

A more efficient version could be

1. Load comments already ordered
2. Load summons already ordered
3. Order comments and summons linearly by scanning each of the two tables in parallel